# How to add libvpx to cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, ffmpeg, libvpx

I need to use vp8 encoder in my c++ project. I have compiled ffmpeg enabling libvpx library using

> ./configure --enable-libvpx

how do I add it to CmakeLists.txt.
I got linking errors when I linked with

> target_link_libraries(main "/path/to/libav")

Comment: "I got linking errors" - This description is quite vague. Please. add to the question post the **exact error message** you got.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using target_link_libraries

`target_link_libraries` expects a full path to a library file, so instead of calling

```
target_link_libraries(main PUB"/path/to/lib")
```

you should do

```
target_link_libraries(main "/path/to/lib/lib.so")
```

#### Using `target_link_directories` and `target_link_libraries`

You can explicitly provide directories, where the linker will look for your libraries. Combining this with `target_link_libraries`, you get

```
target_link_directories(main INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE "/path/to/lib")
target_link_libraries(main lib)
```

#### Using pkg-config

FFmpeg generates pkg-config file, which is a handy solution to handle dependencies.
CMake has a module, which supports pkg-config: [FindPkgConfig](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html)

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
```

It provides a function `pkg_check_modules`, which searches for a .pc file for your library. Supposed you have a file lib.pc you should call

```
pkg_check_modules(LIB lib)
```

You can now link with a library by using specific variables set by pkg-config:

```
target_link_libraries(main ${LIB_LIBRARIES})
target_link_directories(main ${LIB_LIBRARY_DIRS})
target_include_directories(main ${LIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Don't forget to check whether your library was actually found:

```
if(NOT LIB_FOUND)
    # error message
endif()
```